# Getting "Error Code 207" only after deploying WCF services

Tags: wcf, structuremap

I have created a set of WCF services that use StructureMap by following [this](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/07/30/integrating-structuremap-with-wcf/) tutorial. Everything has been working as expected, but it appears that now that I have deployed it to the server, it fails with "Error Code 207: Internal exception while creating Instance".

This error is thrown when my MVC controller method is called via JavaScript to get some data from the service AJAX style.

What is odd is that I can't even hit the first line in the web method that uses the client for the WCF service.

Any ideas on where I can start with this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error occured when you deployed to the server and the first line of your code is not being hit. It is probably a rights issue on the server.

Check:

- Security settings in IIS
- Security settings in web.config
- Are you calling a service on a different server than is serving the page? In this case it could be that cross site scripting is being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error on production.
Turned out that the instance structuremap was creating was throwing an exception
within the constructor due to missing configuration app settings.

So I would advise you check the code in your constructor for any potential errors.
Hope this helps.